# TensorFlow post-LSTM fully connected layer outputs return the same values as each other

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I was trying to train a sequence-to-sequence LSTM model with a dataset with three labels: `[1, 0]` for detection of *class 1*, `[0, 1]` for detection of *class 2*, and `[0, 0]` for detection of nothing. After getting the outputs from the LSTM network, I applied a fully connected layer to each cell's output the following way:

```
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, input)
# Shape of outputs is [batch_size, n_time_steps, n_hidden]

# As matmul works only on matrices, reshape to get the
# time dimension into the batch dimension
outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, n_hidden])
# Shape is [batch_size * n_time_steps, n_hidden]

w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[n_hidden, 2], stddev=0.1))
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[2]))
logit = tf.add(tf.matmul(outputs, w), b, name='logit')

# Reshape back to [batch_size, n_time_steps, 2]
logit = tf.reshape(logit, [batch_size, -1, 2])
```

On the output, I apply `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` and reduce the mean. The model seems to work just fine achieving high accuracy and recall, except for the fact that in almost all the cases it outputs either `[0, 0]`, or `[1, 1]`. The two logit outputs from the fully connected layer always have very similar values (but not the same). This effectively puts a hard-cap on precision of 50%, which the model converges to (but not a fraction of a percent above).

Now, my intuition would tell me that something must be wrong with the training step and both fully connected outputs are trained on the same data, but curiously enough when I replace my own implementation with the prepackaged one from `tf.contrib`:

```
outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, input)
logit = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs, 2, activation_fn=None)
```

*without changing a single other thing*, the model starts training properly. Now, the obvious solution would be to just use that implementation, but why doesn't the first one work?

Comment: The output dimension of `w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[n_hidden, 1], stddev=0.1))` is wrong. It should be `2` not `1`.

Comment: Obviously, you're right. Just an issue of hasty copying to stack overflow, unfortunately. The problem still stands.

Comment: Looks like `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected` uses `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer` for the weights and `tf.zeros_initializer` for the biases by default. Not sure if that shouldn make that much of a difference, but have you tried that? (also there is a missing parenthesis in the line `b = ...`)